# Special Character when using the mailto: option

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, encoding, mailto

I am using a simple mailto option in my html  so that whenever the user clicks on the mailto, it creates a pre defined email with subject and body. The issue is that, the functionality works fine but there is a special character **Â** before the currency symbol and i am clueless what might be the reason.
Also, Weirdly this happens only when i use chrome and **not firefox**. 
(Never tested in IE) 
Any directions on how to proceed with this? 
The code is pretty simple and straight forward

`<a id="body_0_contentcolumn_0_hypOutlook" href="mailto:?subject=test subject&amp;body=Hi, how are you?%0A%0AI wanted to share a job I thought you might be interested in.Salary £15000.00- £25000.00%0A%0AYou can view more details and apply online here:www.apply.com">Outlook
</a>`

Pls find the fiddle below..

[Click here for Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LhFM/)

i am using outlook 2013 and Chrome 33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about encoding.

`£` is character number `0xA3`. This, when encoded "properly" (ie. in UTF-8), is converted to `0xC2A3` - coincidentally, you have the same `A3` in there, which means the rendered result, Â£, looks like it just acquired a "random" Â out of nowhere.

Solution: Encode the `£` properly. Try `&pound;` first, and if that doesn't work try `%A3`.

Comment: Simply Awesome.. %A3 Works just fine. But.. What kind of encoding is this? i tried url, html and utf-8 encoding.. none of them return %A3 for £.

Comment: `%A3` is url-encoding in the iso-8859-1 charset. If you just type `£`, the exact result may vary based on how your source code is encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Per [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068), a "mailto:" link is a series of ASCII characters.  Non-ASCII characters in the body must be represented by UTF-8 ecoding them and then %-encoding the resulting octets.  It makes sense that a browser might try to be friendly by converiting non-ASCII characters in the "mailto:" link that way, but it's also a less-common case. Report a bug against Chrome, but the quick fix may be to do the UTF-8 and %-encoding yourself.